# How to write in table of an html file by clicking on a row of a table in another html file?

Tags: javascript

I have two html files information.html and employee.html.

Information.html contains two tables having IDs 'top' and 'bottom'. Employee.html is included in the `<table id='top'>` of information.html.

Employee.html's code, containing just a dummy `<table>`, is as follows:

```
<!-- employee.html -->
    <table align = "center" border="1" height="100px">
       <tr></b><td><b>No.</b></td><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Age</b></td></tr>

       <script type="text/javascript">
       var i =0;
       for (i= 0;i<20;i++)
       {
      document.write("<tr onclick= '---' ><td><b>" + i);             
        document.write("</b></td><td>Usman</td><td>56</td></tr>");
       }
       </script>
    </table>
```

When i open information.html in my browser, i see employee.html included in the `<table id='top'>` of information.html.

Now, what should i write in **onclick** (in the above code) so that when user click on a row in the table appearing in the 'top' table of information.html, some arbitrary text may appear in the `<table id='bottom'>` of information.html.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the element on the page into which you want to insert the text, this is done using the getElementById function to get the element with id #bottom. Then you can use innerHTML to set the content of the table.

```
document.write("<tr onclick='document.getElementById(\"bottom\").innerHTML = \"some text\"'><td><b>" + i);
```

Don't forget the backslashes, otherwise you might find the quotes won't be escaped properly

Comment: It won't work because employee.html does not know "bottom" because bottom is in another html file titled information.html.

Comment: Not working.

-- bottom -- is not visible to employee.html because table having id=bottom is in information.html, not in employee.html

Comment: How are you including the HTML files into the main page, is it an HTML include or are you doing it via a server-side language?

Comment: e.g. following line of code is used in information.html to include employee.html in the table having id 'top'.

document.getElementById('top').innerHTML = '<iframe frameborder="1" src="'+url+'" width="727px" height="700px"></iframe>';

where url contains the path of the employee.html

Comment: Try this: `document.getElementById('bottom').contentWindow.document.innerHTML = "some text";`